# How to improve this Dynamic programming solution(Optimisation in algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

**The Problem statement:**

Assurance Company of Moving (ACM) is a company of moving things for people. Recently, some schools want to move their computers to another place. So they ask ACM to help them. One school reserves K trucks for moving, and it has N computers to move. In order not to waste the trucks, the school ask ACM to use all the trucks. That is to say, there must be some computers in each truck, and there are no empty trucks. ACM wants to know how many partition shemes exists with moving N computers by K trucks, the ACM ask you to compute the number of different shemes with given N and K. You needn't care with the order. For example N=7,K=3, the the following 3 partition instances are regarded as the same one and should be counted as one sheme: "1 1 5","1 5 1","5 1 1". Each truck can carry almost unlimited computers!!

**Save Time** :

You have to count how many sequences a[1..k] exist such that :

1) a[i] + a[2] + .... + a[k] = N such that permutations dont matter

My O(N*K^2) solution (Cannot figure out how to improve on it)

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int DP[5001][5001];
void ini()
{
    int i,j,k;
    DP[0][0]=1;
    for(k=1;k<=500;k++)
        for(j=1;j<=500;j++)
           for(i=1;i<=500;i++)
            {
                DP[i][j]+=j>=k?DP[i-1][j-k]:0;
                DP[i][j]%=1988;
            }
    return ;
}
int main()
{
    ini();
    int N,K,i,j;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&N,&K);
        if(N==0 && K==0)
            return 0;
        int i;
        if(DP[K][N]==0)
        {assert(0);}
        printf("%d\n",DP[K][N]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation of my solution DP[i][j] represents the number of ways I can have total j computers using i Trucks only.
The k represents the  number of computers with which I am dealing with that means I am just avoiding permutations!

How can I improve it to O(N*K)?

Problem constraints

> N (1<=N<=5000) and K(1<=K<=N)

Problem Link: [Problem Spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/COUNT/)

Comment: Yo, if you xplain yo soln, y dont u include the explanation of the recursive formula ???

Comment: @gen-y-s I made my state clear . I didnt wanted people like you to answer who always have a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to placing `n-k` identical balls (after already placing one ball in each cell to make sure it's not empty) in `k` identical cells.

This can be solved using the recurrence formula:

```
D(n,0) = 0       n > 0
D(n,k) = 0       n < 0
D(n,1) = 1       n >= 0
D(n,k) = D(n,k-1) + D(n-k,k)
```

**Explanation:**

**Stop clauses:**

- D(n,0) - no way to put n>0 balls in 0 cells
- D(n<0,k) - no way to put negative number of balls in k cells
- D(n,1) - one way to put n balls in 1 cell: all in this cell

**Recurrence:**

We have two choices.

1. We either have one (or more) empty cell, so we recurse with the same problem, and one less cell: `D(n,k-1)`
2. Otherwise, we have no empty cells, so we put one ball in each cell, recurse with the same number of cells and k less balls, `D(n-k,k)`

The two possibilities are of disjoint sets, so the union of both sets is the summation of the two sizes, thus `D(n,k) = D(n,k-1) + D(n-k,k)`

The above recursive formula is easy to compute in `O(1)` (assuming `O(1)` arithmetics), if the "lower" problems are known, and the DP solution needs to fill a table of size `(n+1)*(k+1)`, so this solution is `O(nk)`

Comment: I am not getting correct results can you explain where am I going wrong http://ideone.com/CS2EBB

Comment: @Ishu `return recurse(N-1,K-N)+recurse(N-1,K);`, that should be `return recurse(N,K-N)+recurse(N-1,K);` - you shouldn't remove a box if you add  a ball to each cell

Comment: @Ishu Also, note that this solution is not utilizing DP - so it will take a very long time.

Comment: @amit thank you I got my concepts clear and I have a habit of writing bottom up when I have  fully understood the recurrence.

Comment: D(2, 2) gives 2 in your formula, but it should be 1

Comment: @gen-y-s no, it should be 2. (1,1) and (2,0) If you are referring to "no empty cell" I addressed it by mentioning you start from d(n-k,k) instrad of d(n,k). Is the downvote for that?

Answer (score 2):

Just say that you have K gift boxes and N chocolates.

I will start with a recursive and real easy to convert it to iterative solution.

The key to avoid repetitions is distributing chocolates in a ascending order (descending also works). So you 7 chocolates and I put 2 chocolate in the first box, I will put at least `2` in the second box. WHY? this helps in avoiding repetitions.

```
         now onwards TCL = totalChocholatesLeft & TBL  = totalBinsLeft

         So S(TCL,TBL) =  S(TCL-TBL,TBL) + S(TCL,TBL-1);

         you have to call the above expression starting with S(n-k), k)

         Why? because all boxes need at least one item so first put `1` each box. 
         Now you are left with only `n-k` chocolates.
```

That's all! that's the DP recursion.

How does it work?

```
        So in order to remove repetitions we are maintaning the ascending order.
        What is the easiest way to maintain the ascending order ?
```

If you put 1 chocolate in the ith box, put 1 in all boxes in front of it `i+1, i++2 .....k`.
So after keeping chocolate in a gift box, you have two choices :

Either you want to continue with current box :

```
                S(TCL-TBL,TBL) covers this
```

or to move the next box just never consider this box again

```
                S(TCL,TBL-1) covers this.
```

Equivalent DP would make have TC : `O(NK)`

Comment: Nice explanation thanks! By the way I want to clarify when we call  S(TCL,TBL-1) that means we aren't adding any balls to this bin right? I could have never imagined this!

Comment: @Ishu Yes, we are not adding any chocolates to the current bins, but you still keep the sorted order because you have at least as many chocolates as in previous box.